# How to "cd" into all folders step-by-step which are in an text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**UPDATE**

Here's my full code:

```
cd "C:\Users"

DIR /A:D /S /B > "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt" 

type "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt" | findstr /v AppData | findstr /v All.Users | findstr /v Public >> "%appdata%\newfolder.txt"
move "%appdata%\newfolder.txt" "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt"

:repeatuntilfilesizezero
set LINES=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (%appdata%\folder_overview.txt) do (
    set /a LINES=LINES+1
)

set /a LINES=LINES-1
more +%LINES% < "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt" >> "%appdata%\last_folder.txt"

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set content=
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%appdata%\last_folder.txt) do set content=!content! %%i

pause

cd %content%

type "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt" | findstr /v "%content%" >> "%appdata%\newfolder.txt"
move "%appdata%\newfolder.txt" "%appdata%\folder_overview.txt"

DEL "%appdata%\last_folder.txt"

FOR %%S IN (%appdata%\folder_overview.txt) DO set size=%%~zS

echo %size%
IF %size% gtr 0 echo goto :repeatuntilfilesizezero
IF %size% equ 0 echo "null"

pause
```

I noticed that it's totally worth that the last line is a blank line.
I just want the following:

- list all folders
- "cd" to the last folder in "folder_overview.txt" and delete the last line from the file
- check if "folder_overview.txt" is empty
  -> if not empty, just goto label ":repeatuntilfilesizezero"
  -> if empty, goto exit

So finally "cd" step-by-step in all folders which are in "folder_overview.txt".

Currently the "goto :repeatuntilfilesizezero" does not work. It do not jumps to the label.

Hannir

Comment: you want the last non-empty line?

Comment: Why counting? just use `for /F %%L` loop over `folder_overview.txt` with `set "LINE=%%L"` in its body, so `LINE` is overwritten each iteration and will contain last line finally (remember `for /F` skips empty lines on its own)... if `folder_overview.txt` does not contain duplicate lines, you could use `findstr /L /V /X /C` to remove the last line...

Comment: For the command `set content=%content% %%i` you need to enable delayed expansion as it is in a loop, so it must read `set content=!content! %%i`...

Comment: I'll give it a try and reply after. Thx for your quick answer!

Comment: why does `echo goto :label` not go to label? hmmm...

Comment: It is not a good idea to change the scope of a question; rather you should ask another question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't detect what you want to do, but as you `cd` into every directory, I assume you want to do something in every folder in the tree:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\users"
for /f %%i in (' dir /s /b /ad ^|findstr /v "AppData All.Users Public" ') do (
  pushd "%%i"
    echo now working in: %%i
    echo   doing something here in %%~ni
  popd
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to skip some folders? I'd like to skip the folders of "findstr /v AppData | findstr /v All.Users | findstr /v Public". Great work by the way - that's exactly the one I was looking for.

Comment: I'm really thankful for ur code! Thanks alot @Stephan!

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the non-empty last line of a text file, you do not need to count the lines and skip all but one with `more`. Simply use a `for /F` loop with a variable assignment instead, so the variable holds the last line finally:

```
> "%APPDATA%\last_folder.txt" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%APPDATA%\folder_overview.txt") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LINE!
    endlocal
)
```

Delayed variable expansion is used here to avoid trouble with some special characters like `^`, `&`, `(` and `)` in the last line.

---

In case the file does not contain duplicate lines, the following code could be used to remove the last line:

```
> "%APPDATA%\folder_overwiew.txt" findstr /L /X /V /G:"%APPDATA%\last_folder.txt" "%APPDATA%\folder_overwiew.txt"
```

In case the file might contain duplicates, the following snippet could be used instead:

```
set "LINE="
> "%APPDATA%\folder_overwiew.txt" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%APPDATA%\folder_overview.txt") do (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if defined LINE echo(!LINE!
        endlocal
        set "LINE=%%L"
    )
)
```

Comment: if `DIR /A:D /S /B` gives duplicates, you are in trouble, I think :D

Comment: Thanks alot @aschipfl :]